# How to programatically retrieve information from organisation directory?

Tags: html-table, active-directory, search-engine

Background- my organisation have a global directory. The Active Directory only stores the employee numbers and employee name. No information about the role title is stored in Active Directory. (I have already built an LDAP query to retrieve all the information from AD, retrieving the role title is my issue).

On our intranet, there is global directory, which shows the role title. Now this is obvious to me that the role title is stored in some other database.(not AD)

I am wanting to write a script (not sure what to use), to pump a list of employee numbers in the search box and retrieve the role title.
Is this possible? I've never scripted anything to retrieve information from results coming from a website/intranet etc. Any guidance will be appreciated, LDAP queries unfortunately was not the right approach for me as the organisation does not store role title in AD. (I have thousands of employees to find and I don't think it's practical to search individually)

Gemmo

Comment: It's always possible :) but no one here can tell you how because you haven't told us what type of database your other directory is.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I have no idea, and probably direct access is not possible due to authentication. So I was looking for some kind of brute force solution, program the input (employee number) and let the site do the work, since it already have the query written somewhere there. Now I just need to sift through the results inside the HTML? Does that make sense? Since the results are already displayed on a page, I'm sure I can extract it somehow?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but if you don't know what type of system it is, and it's not accessible from the outside, then no one here will be able to help you with it.

Comment: Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you only have access to the front end of this system. It is not ideal, but the only way would be to use [web scraping](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). That is, parse the HTML from the web page.

This method is time consuming to put together and very prone to breaking since it is entirely dependent on how the data is presented on the page. If *anything* changes, your web scraping can break.

But if you will only need to do it once, it might be worth it. A tool [like this one](https://www.webscraper.io) could help you do it. (that is just the first one I found online. There are others, just search.)

But since we can't access this site, we can't really help any more than this.

Web scraping really is the absolute last resort. *Any* other way to get the data is better than this. Maybe you could even ask the administrators of that system to give you a one-time report of just the data you need to see. As long as they're willing, there's no reason they couldn't give you an Excel spreadsheet with the data.

Comment: You are correct, I don't have backend access. The directory however is open to everyone, since I get results back (due to the size of the organisation the admin is hidden away somewhere no one can find). Is this how price comparison website work? Because that's how I got the idea, if a website can pump keywords in multiple websites and return data, I'm sure I can pump multiple keywords in one site and collect the results. (didn't know it was Web Scraping. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: It depends. Some sites have an API to provide access to their products and pricing. For example, Amazon's [Marketplace Web Service](https://developer.amazonservices.com).